# What should I make the type of a "marital status" field?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a field in my table "marital status" , the user has to choose (radiobutton) if he's (married, divorced, single, voeuf)

What should I make the type of this field?

Is there a boolean type?

Comment: In T-SQL a it's a [bit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177603.aspx).

Comment: This depends on what type of SQL database you're using. Please [edit] the question and add a [tag](http://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) to indicate this.

Comment: If there are four possible values, it cannot be a boolean.

Comment: Postgres as a real boolean type, but what you want to store isn't a boolean.

Comment: Check this: http://troels.arvin.dk/db/rdbms/#data_types-boolean

Answer (score 1):

`marital status` doesn't sound like a boolean anyway. It sounds like an enumeration. A boolean would be `married` (Y/N), although I think in this day and age you might want to be able to store multiple kinds of relationships in there, and you specified yourself that you need to store 'devorced' as well, so a boolean is out of the question.

So I'd recommend making a table named MaritalStatus, having an ID and a description. Store the various states in there, and make a foreign key to MaritalStatusID in your table.

Answer (score 1):

Make it an INT field , Create another table in your database something like

```
CREATE TABLE dbo.MaritalStatus
(
M_ID INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL,
M_Status NVARCHAR(20)
)
GO

INSERT INTO  dbo.MaritalStatus
VALUES
(1, 'Single'),(2,'Married'),(3,'Divorced'),
(4,'Widowed'),(5,'Other'),(6,'Prefer Not to say').... bla bla
```

Now in your Table in `"Marital Status" field` refer to a user Marital Status using INT values from `dbo.MaritalStatus` table's `"M_ID"`.

Boolean or in SQL bit datatype is best when you have a situation where something can be TRUE or NOT TRUE, for someone's Marital Status there can be more than two possible values therefore you should create a separate table for all the possible Marital Status and use Foreign key constraint.

Answer (score 0):

The boolean equivalent for T-SQL is `bit`.

Though, it seems like you want more than a yes/no answer. In this case use an int and then convert the int to an enum.

**Edit**: Dukeling removed the C# tag in an edit, so I am not sure how relevant this part is anymore **/Edit**

The enum:

```
enum MaritalStatus
{
   Single,
   Married,
   Divorced,
   ...
}
```

The int from DB:

```
int maritalStatusFromDB = //value from DB
```

Convert int to enum:

```
MaritalStatus maritalStatus = (MaritalStatus)maritalStatusFromDB;
```

Be aware that your database may contain int values that are not defined in your enum, such as 10. You can check whether maritalStatusFromDB is a valid MaritalStatus as follows:

```
bool isValid = Enum.IsDefined(typeof(MaritalStatus), maritalStatusFromDB);
if( isValid == false )
{
    //handle appropriately
}
```